# modify the URDF file for the Turtlebot Burger by adding an extra plate

Tags: urdf, turtlebot3

I'm looking to modify the URDF file for the Turtlebot3 Burger robot. My goal is to introduce an additional plate in the middle of the robot's structure. This alteration in the design would impact the robot's height and subsequently elevate the position of the plate equipped with the LiDAR sensor. The purpose behind incorporating this middle plate is to accommodate a cup, as the robot serves the function of a coffee delivery agent. I'm relatively new to working with URDF files and could use some assistance in understanding how to effectively use and modify them. Could you please guide me on how to implement these changes effectively within the URDF file?

We attempted to explore methods for implementing these modifications using Blender and SolidWorks. However, we encountered challenges as Blender 2.9 with Phobos didn't yield the desired results, and unfortunately, SolidWorks is not an available tool in our current toolkit.